# How to show all hidden controls of a Form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

In C# form window, say i have 5 controls. I have just hide some of them. When I run the program just the (Visible=true) controls should appear. I want to click a button to appear or unhide all controls. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it recursive, then if you have any panels/group boxes their children get made visible too.

```
public void MakeVisible(Control control)
{
    if(control.HasChildren)
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            MakeVisible(child);
        }
    }
    control.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Winforms, try this:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls) {
    c.Visible = true;
}
```

This code loops through all controls on your form and sets the [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) property to true, to make each one visible.

Comment: @H.Wardak: Why would you care that it is recursive?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to change the visible propery in the code behind.

e.g.

```
button1.visible = true;
```

and do that for each hidden control, button or not.

Just to add I doubt you would want to do the loop through all controls that everyone else suggests. Changing the visibility on everything on your form is a waste of time and can lead to complications further down the track if you make only certain controls visible during different scenarios.

Since it is only 5 controls, I would stick with changing each one individually.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
foreach (var controlObj in form.Controls)
    ((Control)controlObj).Visible = True;
```

should do the trick. This simply shows *all* controls in the form. (Note that `Form.Controls`is an untyped Collection containing only `Object`s, so you have to cast them afair)

If you have only 5 controls, you could also show them individually, perhaps in a method like

```
void showHiddenControls(bool show) {
  control1.Visible = show;
  control2.Visible = show;
  // ...
}
```

This has the advantage that you can show them using `showHiddenControls(true)` and hide them again using `showHiddenControls(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide/show everything,

```
    foreach (Control cr in this.Controls)
        cr.Visible = false; // or true, if you want to show everything
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea would be to create objects like that :

```
Label toto = new Label():
(...) Do whatever you wan't to initialize your object
toto.Visible = false;

Button makeItAppear = new Button();
(..) Do whatever you wan't to initialize this button
```

And then add an handler on the click event :

```
makeItAppear.Click += new System.EventHandler(MakeItAppear);
```

And then in the eventHandler :

```
private void MakeItAppear(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.toto.Visible = true;
}
```

The best would be to create a function which make this appear and which is called by the Handler. And of course, if you have multiple object to make appear or disappear do the same for all in this function.