# Cross-thread operation not valid and Invoke statement

Tags: c#, invoke

I have a Mainform with many controls on it.Now I'm trying to access this controls from a thread.Should I use invoke statement for each instruction?!!! or there is another way? a piece of my code is:

```
     switch (currentSetting.CurrentFFMDisplayMode)
                    {
                        case FFM_DisplayMode.Polar:
                            this.display.Visible = false;
                            this.gauge1.init(10000, 450);
                            this.gauge1.Visible = true;
                            this.AzimuthWaterfall.Visible = false;
                            this.FreqWaterfall.Visible = false;
                            this.histogram1.Visible = false;
                            this.LevelSlider.Visible = true;
                            this.QualitySlider.Visible = true;
                            this.LevelSlider.Visible = true;
                            this.QualitySlider.Visible = true;
                            this.textBoxLevel.Visible = true;
                            this.textBoxQuality.Visible = true;
                            this.textBoxAzimuth.Visible = true;
                            this.textBoxPrevious.Visible = true;
                            this.textBoxfloatE.Visible = true;
                            this.labelPrevious.Visible = true;

                            this.labelLevelErr.Visible = false;
                            this.labelQualityErr.Visible = false;
                            this.LevelLine.Visible = false;
                            this.Levelarraw.Visible = false;
                            this.freqLine.Visible = false;
                            this.spectVLine.Visible = false;
                            this.labelSNR.Visible = false;
                            this.button_dec_freq_spec.Visible = false;
                            this.button_inc_freq_spec.Visible = false;
                            this.combobox_Span.Visible = false;
                            this.label_Spectrum.Visible = false;
                            this.FreqLable.Visible = false;

                            label1.Visible = true;
                            label2.Visible = true;
                            label3.Visible = true;
                            label4.Visible = true;
                            label5.Visible = true;
                            label6.Visible = true;
                            label7.Visible = true;
                            label8.Visible = true;
                            label9.Visible = true;
                            label10.Visible = true;
                            label11.Visible = true;
                            label12.Visible = true;
                            l20.Visible = true;
                            LevelTHlabel.Visible = true;
                            qTHlabel.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* surround the entire switch statement in an anonymous method like so:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
{
     switch (currentSetting.CurrentFFMDisplayMode) 
     {
          case FFM_DisplayMode.Polar:
              this.display.Visible = false;
              ...
     }

}));
```

But to avoid excessive nesting I would bring the switch statement out into another method:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    switch (currentSetting.CurrentFFMDisplayMode) 
    {
        case FFM_DisplayMode.Polar:
            this.display.Visible = false;
             ...
    }
}
...

this.Invoke(new Action(DoSomething));
```

By the way, you may well be able to reduce the length (and consistently, the readability) of the case statement by selectively iterating the controls of your form as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8600853/2015959).